# Proof that Legendre symbol is multiplicative

Tags: quadratic-residues

I want to proof that the Legendre symbol is multiplicative. Therefore I use the Criterion by Euler whih claims, that for an integer $a$ and an odd prime $p$ it holds
$$
\big( \frac{a}{q} \big) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (\bmod p).
$$

My theorem:
Let $a$ be an integer with it's prime decomposition
$$
a = \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\alpha_p}.
$$
Furthermore, let $q$ be an odd prime. Then it holds
$$
\big( \frac{a}{q} \big) 
=
 \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}\big( \frac{p}{q} \big) ^{\alpha_p}.
$$
Proof:
We have
$$
\big( \frac{a}{q} \big) 
\equiv
a^{\frac{q-1}{2}}
\equiv
\big( \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\alpha_p} \big) ^{\frac{q-1}{2}}
\equiv
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\alpha_p\cdot\frac{q-1}{2}}
\equiv
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\frac{q-1}{2}\cdot\alpha_p}
\equiv
\big( \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \big) ^{\alpha_p}(\bmod q),
$$
which follows by the known properties of products.
Again by the Euler criterion it follows that
$$
\big( \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \big) ^{\alpha_p}(\bmod q)
\equiv
\big( \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}\big( \frac{p}{q}\big)\big) ^{\alpha_p}(\bmod q)
$$
and finally
$$
\big( \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}\big( \frac{p}{q}\big)\big) ^{\alpha_p}(\bmod q)
\equiv
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P} \big(\frac{p}{q}\big) ^{\alpha_p}(\bmod q).
$$

Do I miss something?
And I wonder whether I know may write
$$
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P} \big(\frac{p}{q}\big) ^{\alpha_p}(\bmod q) = 
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P} \big(\frac{p}{q}\big) ^{\alpha_p},
$$
because I "leave" the congruence here for an equality.

Comment: This has been asked before. My advice is to just focus on the "is it a square?" criterion (the initial definition)

Comment: @FShrike I checked for duplicate but could not find it.